# Sending Data over MQTT: JSON vs STRING

Tags: c

After a lot of effort to program my board, I am finally able to send a simple message over MQTT using Mosquitto broker and Paho based client. At this point I have a doubt. I am sending to the client a simple string, but I want obviously send the result of another operation (such as a Data ACquisition, positioning service, etc).
What should I do in this case?
I read that payload of function below must be a string and I read also that I sould send JSON file:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQAsK.png)
What do you advise me to do in these cases? Should I create a JSON file at the end of every function that I want to send?
Any help will be appreciated.
Best Regards

Comment: The process of converting data to a sequence of bytes (e.g. so you can send or store them) is called *serialization*. JSON is one way to serialize data, and a very convenient one.

Comment: Okay, so if I have a function that claculates device position, have I to serialize calculated data through JSON and then send through a conversion using the sprintf function. Do you agree?